# Universal Windows Platform (UWP): Assertion failure after taking a picture

Tags: c#, camera, uwp

[image]Sometimes i get the error "Assertion Failure" after taking a picture with the camera. It's hard to reproduce and i have no idea why it happens. The last text i see in the console is "taking picture". I don't have any idea why it happens so this is kindof a last resort. I know that this isn't alot of code to look at, but if you got any idea's on how to solve this kind of error in please comment or answer

```
public async Task<IBuffer> TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("taking picture...");

        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            try
            {
                await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);
                Debug.WriteLine("captured to stream");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Instance.HandleException(e);
            }

            IBuffer ibuffer = await StreamHelpers.StreamToIBuffer(stream);
            Debug.WriteLine("picture taken, buffer retreived");
            return ibuffer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enable mixed mode debugging. Debugger will break on the assertion failure and you'll be able to see the callstack.